# How to exclude rows from a SQL fetch that have a related keyword through a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a `media` table, and a `keywords` table, and a many-to-many relationship between `media` and `keywords` via a `media_keywords` join table.

I want to fetch all records from the media table where the following set of conditions match:

```
'description' is like 'dog' OR 
'media.keywords' includes the id for the 'dog' keyword [100]
```

And exclude from the found set any records where:

```
'description' is like 'cat' OR
'media.keywords' includes the id for the 'cat' keyword [400]
```

And also exclude any row where:

```
'media.keywords' includes the id for the 'monochrome' keyword [500]
```

I also want to return only distinct rows, so I'm using GROUP By 'media.id'

The SQL statement I have at the moment is as follows:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    `media`.`id`,`media`.`description`, 
    `keywords`.`id` AS `keywords.id`, 
    `keywords->media_keywords`.`id` AS `keywords.media_keywords.id`, 
    `keywords->media_keywords`.`media_id` AS `keywords.media_keywords.media_id`, 
    `keywords->media_keywords`.`keyword_id` AS `keywords.media_keywords.keyword_id` 

    FROM database.media 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ( 
        `media_keywords` AS `keywords->media_keywords` 

        INNER JOIN `keywords` AS `keywords` 
        ON `keywords`.`id` = `keywords->media_keywords`.`keyword_id`
    ) 

    ON `media`.`id` = `keywords->media_keywords`.`media_id` 

    WHERE 
    ( 
            (`media`.`description` LIKE '%dog%' ) 

            OR `keywords`.`id` IN (100) 
    )

    AND NOT 
    ( 
            (`media`.`description` LIKE '%cat%' ) 

            OR `keywords`.`id` IN (400,500)
    )

    GROUP BY `media`.`id` ;
```

This correctly fetches records where 'dog' is in the description or is a keyword, but ignores the exclusions completely.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your aliases are longer than your table names. I feel ill.

Comment: Also, it's unlikely that you're using a case sensitive collation- just sayin'

Comment: And do you want to exclude words like 'scathing' ?

Comment: @Strawberry - I checked, and you're correct, the collation is case insensitive, so the lower() wasn't necessary - and I've removed it. I'm a front end developer learning the back end, and finding the signal to noise ratio online is low at best, so I'm sure there are lots of things I'm not doing to the best standard. I'm not crushed by scathing comments, but I do much prefer the more helpful ones. If you've got suggetions as to how to solve this problem more efficiently, that's what I'm looking to hear and they'd be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: It's just a question, and see my earlier comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `where` clause:

```
select m.*
from media m
where (m.description like '%dog%' or
       exists (select 1
               from keywords k
               where k.media_id = m.id and
                     k.keyword_id = 100
              )
      ) and
      (m.description not like '%cat%' or
       exists (select 1
               from keywords k
               where k.media_id = m.id and
                     k.keyword_id in (400, 500)
              )
       );
```

This is pretty much a direct translation of your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with mySQL much, but I would suggestion a different approach

- Move the "DOG" condition inside the LEFT JOIN (so only get keywords
  matching "DOG") and make it a JOIN.   Now you'll have a list of all
  matches.
- add a subquery in the WHERE clause
- WHERE id not in (SELECT id FROM ... WHERE LIKE '%cat%')